# Is there way of stopping uint underflow in C#?

Tags: c#, underflow

Use int to test if below 0 .
uint in c# wraps around to a huge number once it goes below 0, this is in all programming languages.

Comment: Not possible sadly

Comment: Why not check if your uint is bigger than the number you're subtracting before you subtract it? If it isn't, set your uint to 0.

Comment: One of the most useful and most overlooked build options is Project > Properties > Build tab > Advanced button, "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow".  Ideal in the Debug configuration and ideally suited to remind you to write the code to stop underflow where necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
uint i = 0;
i = checked(i - 1);
```

This will throw `System.OverflowException`. Though it will not stay zero, at least you will be sure that no overflow happened.

Comment: I didn't want this this way, it will slow down my app too much.

Answer (score -2):

I just use ordinary int instead of uint, and check if its < 0... problem solved

Comment: Considering you are answering your own question (which generally isn't a problem), _why_ did you pick `uint` in the first place.  Surely it was for the positive range.  I feel this question-answer pair isn't useful

Comment: i thought if uint goes below 0 it stays 0

Comment: ...and if you decrement an `int` value of `-2,147,483,648` it suddenly wraps round to `2,147,483,647` and vice versa.  These are all symptoms of how integer values are stored in binary